# Cart form view - relation to product variation doubles number of rows?

Tags: 8, views, commerce

I'm editing standard "Cart form" Drupal commerce view. I need to get some field from product variation, but by default setup it's not available. So I added relationship product variation and field is available now, but I got doubled number of rows?!? Only difference is that first row version doesn't have value of that field from product variation and second one does. Beside that they are identical.

Tried using distinct, but didn't help. With aggregation I get some ultra long error message that starts with:

*"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'commerce_order_item_commerce_order__order_items.unit_price__' in 'field list': SELECT commerce_order_item_commerce_order__order_items.purchased_entity AS commerce_order_item_commerce_order__order_items_purchased_en, commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_order_item__commerce_product_variation__field_summary_title.field_summary_title_value AS commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_order_item__c, commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_order_item.langcode AS commerce_product_variation_field_data_commerce_order_item_la, commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product_variation_field_data__commerce_product__field_summary_title.field_summary_title_value AS commerce_product_field_data_commerce_product_variation_field, ..."*

Distinct helps only have relationship with product variation, but  I don't add that field form it. But in that case I don't need that relationship at all, right?

What I'm doing wrong? Why form cat view returns doubled results when I add relationship to product variation?

Update:

Tried catching results in hook_views_pre_render() to remove faulty rows from there, but there all rows look ok and I can not distinct which one is ok and which on is missing field value.

```
    foreach($view->result as $row){
      $productVariation = $row->_relationship_entities['commerce_product_variation'];
       $fieldValue = $productVariation->get('field_name')->getString();
...
```

Comment: Works as expected for me, no duplicates. What version of commerce are you using?

Comment: I'm using v. 8.x-2.20